# don't show the page until get the response from $http.get

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angular js for my page. when I run it on my localhost it needs to go for remote server to get some data. I am getting data from '$http.get' which actually somewhat delayed(3-4 secs) so, mean-while the html page looks ugly. I need to prevent to show the page until the response data returned.

How can I achieve this ?

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: its called FOUC. google it

Comment: Looking for `resolve` in Angular I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a variable to your scope that's 'false' by default. When your '$http.get' call is done, set the variable to 'true'.

Use 'ng-show="variable"' on whatever you want to hide. It will show whenever that variable is set to 'true'. E.g. when the '$http.get' call is completed.

UPDATE:
If you want to make it more fancy, you can use classes instead of true / false for your variable and use 'ng-class="variable"' to style your page. This way, you can use a class, let's say 'hidden' to hide the page. And then change it to 'shown' when the '$http.get' call is completed. This way, you can use CSS3 transitions.

I believe there are other options as well, but this could be a simple solution. For the best solution, you should provide more info. (how is the call made, when is the call made, ...)

Answer (score 2):

you have two ways to solve it

1. ng-cloak: You have to add it like this:

   ```
   <body ng-cloak="">
   ```

also you would need this class somewhere in your main css file.

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

and this will prevent unwanted flashing.
[Link to docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak).

OR 2. you can use ng-route resolve

you should return a promise from your route, and route change only after the promise is reoslved.

```
.when('/article/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'app/article/article.html',
    controller: 'ArticleController',
    resolve: {
        article: ['$http', '$route', function ($http, $route) {
            return $http.get({ contentId: $route.current.params.id }).$promise;
        }]
    }
})
```

Comment: What is `Content` here in the example ?

Comment: @HarishR... where "{{ bodyClass }}" should be declared actually.

Comment: Yeah it looks `promise`ing now instead of a Service to a new comer +1

Comment: @NawazishSE remove the body class, it was not mandatory. whats important is placement of ng-cloak rather than the class. removed un-ncessary distractions from example

Comment: it's not working for me as I am using <body ng-controller="searchCtrl" ng-cloak="">. do I need any further modification.